# How to set map to center on a marker? - Angular Google Maps

Tags: angular, geolocation, marker, angular-google-maps

I cannot center my Google map on a marker after I geocode.

I have two markers: The initial marker (the one that is centered on, does not change), the other one changes based on the geocoding, and after geocoding, it will be centered on every time.

My code: **TS**

```
zoom = 10;

addressData: FormGroup;
submitted = false;
success = false;

lat: number;
lng: number;

userLat: number;
userLng: number;

currentCenter = { lat: null, lng: null };

private geoCoder: google.maps.Geocoder;

@ViewChild('googleMap') googleMap: AgmMap;

constructor(private maps: MapsAPILoader, private bulider: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.addressData = this.bulider.group({
        address: ["", Validators.required],
    });

    this.maps.load().then(() => {
        this.geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    });
}

getAddress() {

    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.addressData.invalid) {
        return;
    }

    this.success = true;

    this.googleMap.mapReady.subscribe(map => {

        // Need to use two parameters in order to use Geocoder
        this.geoCoder.geocode(this.addressData.controls['address'].value, (results, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            this.userLat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            this.userLng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }

    }).then(place => {
        this.currentCenter = { lat: place.geometry.location.lat(), lng: place.geometry.location.lng() };
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Error: " + err);
    });

    this.submitted = false;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Google maps, the starting latitude & longitude -->
<agm-map [latitude]="currentCenter.lat" [longitude]="currentCenter.lng" [zoom]="zoom" [mapTypeControl]='true'
#googleMap>
    <!-- Static marker -->
    <agm-marker [latitude]="defaultCenter.lat" [longitude]="defaultCenter.lng"></agm-marker>

    <!-- User geolocation marker, changes -->
    <agm-marker [latitude]="currentCenter.userLat" [longitude]="currentCenter.userLng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

**Expected**:

After Geocoding, the map should center on the marker from the given address *every* time.

**Actual**:

The Geocoder finds the address but does not center the map on the placed marker based on the address.

**Update**

I cannot use Vadim's code because the compiler tells me that I need two arguments for the `Geocode`, but Vadim's code only has one. I cannot use this code. Also, if I add the second argument, it will then say that `then` does not exist.

```
this.googleMap.mapReady.subscribe(map => {
    // This line needs two parameters not one      

    this.geoCoder.geocode(this.addressData.controls['address'].value)
    .then(place => {
        this.currentCenter = { lat: place.geometry.location.lat(), lng: place.geometry.location.lng() };
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Error: " + err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to resort to Google Maps API or invoke Map component `triggerResize` method, to update map center the following approach could be considered:

a) set map center to *default* value once the map is loaded

```
<agm-map
  [latitude]="currentCenter.lat"
  [longitude]="currentCenter.lng"
  [zoom]="zoom"
  [mapTypeControl]="true"
>
  <!-- Static marker -->
  <agm-marker
    [latitude]="defaultCenter.lat"
    [longitude]="defaultCenter.lng"
  ></agm-marker>

  <!-- User geolocation marker, changes -->
  <agm-marker
    [latitude]="currentCenter.lat"
    [longitude]="currentCenter.lng"
  ></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

For that matter two properties are introduced:

- `currentCenter` - current map center
- `defaultCenter` - default (original) map center

b) once the address is resolved, update map center like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.agmMap.mapReady.subscribe(map => {
      this.geocode("New York, USA").then(place => {
        this.currentCenter = { lat: place.geometry.location.lat(), lng: place.geometry.location.lng()};
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
 }
```

**Example**

```
declare var google: any;

import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import { AgmMap } from "@agm/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-map",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  defaultCenter = {lat: 55.5815245, lng: 36.8251383};
  currentCenter = Object.assign({}, this.defaultCenter);
  zoom = 3;

  @ViewChild(AgmMap) agmMap;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.agmMap.mapReady.subscribe(map => {
      this.geocode("New York, USA").then(place => {
        this.currentCenter = { lat: place.geometry.location.lat(), lng: place.geometry.location.lng()};
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }

  geocode(address: string): Promise<any> {
    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      geocoder.geocode(
        {
          address: address
        },
        (results, status) => {
          if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            resolve(results[0]);
          } else {
            reject(new Error(status));
          }
        }
      );
    });
  }
}
```

**Update**

Getting address from input element:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="addressText">
<button (click)="findPlace()">Find a place</button>


findPlace() {
    this.geocode(this.addressText).then(place => {
      this.currentCenter = { lat: place.geometry.location.lat(), lng: place.geometry.location.lng()};
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Since my address is a variable, unlike yours, is it possible to pass a variable to the `this.geocode(var in here)` method? And not like this: `this.geocode("New York, USA")`.

Comment: @Compilerv2, the way how address is getting passed into geocode function is not really relevant here.. what matters is updating Map component `center` data-bound property and let Angular do the rest

Comment: Apparently, `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.`, I cannot use the `then()` method because it does not exist for the `geocode()`. Also, I had to use (look in my updated question) 2 parameters in order to use the geocoder. I cannot use one like you've shown.

Comment: Can you please start a StackBlitz?

Answer (score 1):

Parsing to the number will fix the issue when assigning the new values which coming from back-end

```
setLatLongValue(lat,long) {
    this.lat = Number(lat);
    this.lng = Number(long);    
  }
```

Please follow the link to get complete example [Angular – Recenter Angular Google Maps ( AGM )](https://codinghub.net/article/recenter-angular-google-maps-using-agm)

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the `triggerResize()` method

> gets called with the current lat/lng values or fitBounds value to recenter the map

https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/agmmap#triggerResize

However you do not update the longitude/latitude of the map, since you bound the property to `initLat` and `initLng`.
`<agm-map [latitude]="initLat" [longitude]="initLng" [zoom]="zoom">`

You need to update the *map* coordinates in order to recenter on `triggerResize()`. Be careful that you bind your template to the right attribute in your class. In the ts snippet that you showed `userLat` and `userLng` are not present so your geolocated marker will also be problematic.

Updated template:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" [mapTypeControl]='true'>
<!-- Static marker -->
<agm-marker [latitude]="initLat" [longitude]="initLng"></agm-marker>

<!-- User geolocation marker, changes -->
<agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

You might need to initialise `lat` and `lng` to some value in your ts file.

Comment: I have two markers, one of which (The initial one) I do not change. The `lat` & `lng` are the ones that change based on the geocoding. So your answer is not helpful.

Comment: The markers are irrelevant for the map. If you want to use the `triggerResize()` method you must update it's coordinates. If you don't, nothing will happen. You can still bind your first marker to other coordinates like `init` if you want, those are separates.